# WWW subdomain not secured even though redirection is applied

Tags: ssl, nginx, dns, digital-ocean

I am trying attempting to get the 'www' sub-domain redirected to the same route without the 'www' but when accessing the address i receive the following error:

Your connection is not private
Attackers might be trying to steal your information from www.*.com (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). Learn more
NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

The sub-domain without the 'www' is fully active and set up with an SSL i've made using Lets Encrypt (both version of the sub-domains were registered when creating the SSL).

When doing a curl command on the 'www' domain i successfully get a '301 Moved Permanently'.

Here is the configuration file of my nginx:

```
# HTTP — redirect all traffic to HTTPS
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
    return 301 sitename.com$request_uri;
}

# HTTPS — proxy all requests to the Node app
server {
    # Enable HTTP/2
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name sitename.com;

    # Use the Let’s Encrypt certificates
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/sitename.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/sitename.com/privkey.pem;

    # Include the SSL configuration from cipherli.st
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4000/;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've decided to tackle this issue in another way. I generated another Lets Encrypt SSL certificate for the 'www' subdomain and created another block.

Now everything works as expected.

Here is my updated config:

```
# HTTP — redirect all traffic to HTTPS
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name sitename.com www.sitename.com;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

# HTTPS — proxy all requests to the Node app
server {
    # Enable HTTP/2
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name sitename.com;

    # Use the Let’s Encrypt certificates
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/sitename.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/sitename.com/privkey.pem;

    # Include the SSL configuration from cipherli.st
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4000/;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}

# HTTPS — proxy all requests to the Node app
server {
    # Enable HTTP/2
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name www.sitename.com;

    # Use the Let’s Encrypt certificates
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.sitename.com-0001/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.sitename.com-0001/privkey.pem;

    # Include the SSL configuration from cipherli.st
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4000/;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*edited, see comment*

You could try a more complete solution. Using wildcards and a improved redirect. Please try it!

```
# HTTP — redirect all traffic to HTTPS
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    server_name .sitename.com;     # Note the '.' before sitename!

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

# HTTPS — proxy all requests to the Node app
server {
    # Enable HTTP/2
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name .sitename.com;

    # Use the Let’s Encrypt certificates
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/sitename.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/sitename.com/privkey.pem;

    # Include the SSL configuration from cipherli.st
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4000/;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

[Docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html)

`.sitename.com`;

> A special wildcard name in the form “.example.org” can be used to match both the exact name “example.org” and the wildcard name “*.example.org”.

Comment: I've added the subdomain as suggested but the issue still persists

Comment: @Richard, ive edited my post with a more complete config. Changed the server_name and the :80 return type, no more hard coded, but with nginx vars to redirect to https.(Was missing). PLease let me know if this works for you. If not, please share the errors found in `/var/www/nginx/error.log`